# The word for a person who rides a train next to the driver, making sure everything is done right

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

There's this procedure in train companies that an instructor comes and rides along, next to the driver, checking that everything is done according to the rules. While doing that, he or she doesn't provide any additional instructions, doesn't assist the driver in any way, just observing. What is the proper word/phrase for that person and the job/activity?

Comment: The generic terms would be **observer** or **evaluator**.  I can think of no more specific term that means "one whose job is to observe  and evaluate trainees and report their findings". Individual organizations might give that person a particular title, but it would be a phrase, not a single word, for example "Trainees Evaluator" or "Trainees Observer", which is not to be confused with "Trainee Observer", which is a trainee who observes experts doing their jobs, as a learning experience.

Comment: You could also call them an **assessor**, **examiner** or **inspector** (although the term _inspector_ can be used to mean _ticket inspector_, so could be confusing). I can't think of a train-specific term (although I have never worked in that field, there may be one).

Answer (score 1):

They are traditionally called [Road Foremen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_foreman_of_engines).

However, you may very will find the exact Personnel title in a given operator, CSX/BNSF for example, to be different.

Also note, this may be a US specific term.